What would be the best position in pick order when picking a card out of a bowl with one bad card?
Let's say there are 10 people, and each person has to pick a random card out of a bowl consisting of 10 cards; 9 good ones and 1 bad one. I was wondering what position to pick a card from the bowl would be best mathematically so as to not get the bad card. Would it be first since that theoretically gives you the best ratio of good ones to bad ones, or would it be last since the bad card would most likely have been pulled already by someone before you? Or perhaps somewhere in the middle?

Assuming you take a card without replacing it back, or if you do replace it back you continue until all have taken (and replaced) a card and there can be multiple "losers"... all positions are equally likely to have picked "the bad card."  There is no "best position."

There may be a simpler approach, but I think this one is understandable. Let...

$n$ ... number of all cards.
$p$ ... position of player ($p$-th person to draw a card).

It is easier to calculate the probability to draw the one "bad" card. At position $p$ (counting 1,2,3,...n), there are $(n-p+1)$ cards left, and so the probability at this position is
$$\frac{1}{n-p+1}$$
(e.g. at position $p=1$, there are $n$ cards left, at position $p=n$, there is only one card left,...)
However, in order for the player to draw the bad card at position $p$, the NPCs must have drawn good cards. One therefore has
$$P(\text{bad}) = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-3}{n-2} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n-p+1}{n-p+2} \cdot \frac{1}{n-p+1}$$
But these fractions do cancel nicely in the following way
$$P(\text{bad};p) = \frac{\color{red}{n-1}}{n} \cdot \frac{\color{blue}{n-2}}{\color{red}{n-1}} \cdot \frac{\color{green}{n-3}}{\color{blue}{n-2}} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{\color{orange}{n-p+1}}{\color{purple}{n-p+2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\color{orange}{n-p+1}}$$
so that the probability to draw the "bad" card is independent from the position.
$$\boxed{P(\text{bad};p) = \frac{1}{n}}$$
Trivially, the provability to draw a "good card" at position $p$ is
$$P(\text{good};p) = 1 - P(\text{bad};p)$$

Suppose the ten people each pick their card one at a time, but don't look at their cards until all have been picked. That's clearly the same as shuffling the ten cards and dealing them out. Then they look, one at a time. The probability that you have the bad card is $1/10$, no matter where you are in the order.
